# fft() get amplitude, frequency, phase and invert back in series

Tags: r, signal-processing, fft

I am very bad at spectral analysis, so please forgive me for stupid questions.
I found someone's code on the net to calculate the amplitude of the frequency and phase

```
y <- rnorm(50) # some series
samp.freq <- 10
N <- length(y)
fk <- fft(y)
fk <- fk[2:length(fk)/2+1]
fk <- 2*fk[seq(1, length(fk), by = 2)]/N


freq <- (1:(length(fk)))*samp.freq/(2*length(fk))
amp <- Mod(fk)
pha <- Arg(fk)
```

My question is: knowing `freq ,amp, pha` how can I restore back the `y` series

This code is not obligatory for me, it is important for me to see how I can get the amplitude, frequency, phase from the series, and then assemble the series back

Comment: in many languages this is bundled into very high level operations however the process to to start from the frequency domain ( freq, amplitude, phase ) and transform this data into the time domain is called an Inverse Fourier Transform  ... iterate across each freq ... for each freq synthesize an oscillator at that freq and at that amplitude and phase offset for some period of time ( note freq domain has no notion of time) ... now you iterate across each of these oscillator waves at a given time point to output its aggregate normalized value ( avg height of the curve across all oscil curves)

Comment: this give you a height of the curve in your final output in the time domain ... continue to advance your time point to generate a new aggregate curve height as you visit that next time point across each oscillator output ... confirm your time domain output curve is solid by feeding it into a FFT call and this new output should match your original source freq domain signal

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but without the code it is quite difficult to understand what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to restore fully the timeseries as `fft` result is subsampled :

```
fk <- 2*fk[seq(1, length(fk), by = 2)]/N
```

meaning you're losing some frequencies.

Without subsampling, restoration can be done with inverse `fft` :

```r
set.seed(123)
y <- rnorm(50) # some series
samp.freq <- 10
N <- length(y)
fk <- fft(y)

# No subsampling
#fk <- fk[2:length(fk)/2+1]
#fk <- 2*fk[seq(1, length(fk), by = 2)]/N

freq <- (1:(length(fk)))*samp.freq/(2*length(fk))
amp <- Mod(fk)
pha <- Arg(fk) 

fk.restored <- amp * complex(real = cos(pha),im = sin(pha))
y.restored <- Re(fft(fk.restored,inverse=TRUE)/length(fk))
all.equal(y.restored,y)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i need!
Should the variable "y.restored" be "fk.restored" and not just "fk" ?

Comment: And can you give an example of how I can change the frequency and restore the series, because I do not see the frequency in the calculations, or this is beyond the scope of my question

Comment: `samp_freq` is 10 Herz, allowing to calculate `freq`, the frequencies used for `fft` calculation. The other way round, 50 data points sampled at 10 Herz gives a timeseries with `t=(1:50)/10`